# Does HasNext exists in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, arraylist

How do I test in ASP if there is next element in a list?
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
a=Split("foo, boo, luu, bar", ",")
for each x in a
    response.write("'" & x & "'")       
    if a.HasNext then
        response.write(",")
    end if
next
```

How does it works?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you want the reverse of Split? If so just use `Response.Write(Join(a, "<br />"))` and see what you get.

Comment: Interesting... =) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no HasNext but you can test against the size of the array

```
a=Split("foo, boo, luu, bar", ",")
i = 0
for each x in a
    response.write("'" & x & "'")       
    if i < Ubound(a) then
        response.write(",")
    end if
    i = i + 1
next
```